# Force an element to be atop every single other element (Even fullscreen mode)

Tags: css, html, angular

Is it possible to force an element (lets say a div) atop every single other element as well as fullscreen (from video tag/iframe).

At the moment I'm trying with:

- position: absolute
- z-index: 2147483647

But it doesn't seem to go over fullscreen. (Tested on Chrome - 61.0.3163.100)

Why do I want to do this?
I want to display a kind of Notification I guess over fullscreen, so when they are watching an embed youtube video on the site, I can show them a notification that they normally wont see and might miss when in fullscreen.

<strike>It seems this has changed since recent releases of chrome as other SO answers proceed to give the suggestion I tried above and it has worked for them. Seemingly chrome changed something stopping this from working.</strike>
Seems to actually be because im trying to do this with a Angular Material component and for some reason something doesnt allow this to occur.

After checking it seems chrome doesn't even change anything to do with z-index in :-webkit-full-screen yes setting z-index on the fullscreen item and/or the div, wont work still.

Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example:
<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/ea3rbmo4/</strike>

Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/bw2ytwwb/
This one shows you exactly whats wrong, the red div goes in front, but the md-toast fails to.

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    md-toast {
        z-index: 2147483647!important;
        position: absolute!important;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- Angular Controllers -->
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate']);
      app.controller('body', ['$scope', '$mdToast', function($scope, $mdToast) {
        $mdToast.show(
          $mdToast.simple()
          .textContent("Test123")
          .position('top right')
          .hideDelay(999999)
        );
      }]);
    </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="body" layout="column" layout-align="center center" layout-fill style="background:#22282b">
    <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media" type="video/mp4" src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, please include a [mcve].

Comment: @TylerH Ok strangely after recreating it in JSFiddle it works, but it doesnt seem to work on AngularJS's Toast (Angular Material) https://jsfiddle.net/zhmnsyay/ <- non Toast working, but AngularJS Toast doesnt work for some reason?

Comment: @TylerH Added a MCaV example of the issue.

Comment: Still need help on this :(